# Undefined sslv3_method in m2crypto

Tags: python, heroku, swig, m2crypto

I'm running a django app on heroku, which requires m2crypto for some functionality, however a simple import gives the following error:

`ImportError: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/M2Crypto/_m2crypto.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sslv3_method`

I have seen a similar question on Stack overflow, but the suggested answer i.e. to apt-get install it is not available to me as I am running this on heroku. I am using [this](https://github.com/jamarparris/heroku-buildpack-python-swig) buildpack for installing SWIG.

Answer (score 1):

File a bug with Heroku. M2Crypto has to be built against the particular version of Python and especially particular version of OpenSSL. If they upgraded the latter and not rebuilt M2Crypto, it would be the issue.